# Scala multipolygon to h3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, h3, geospark

I'm following this tutorial https://www.databricks.com/notebooks/geomesa-h3-notebook.html and have encountered a problem. Namely the multiPolygonToH3 function fills only the first polygon.

This is my multiPolygon

```
MULTIPOLYGON(((37.60574672029919 55.76360304012307,37.62162539766735 55.76360304012307,37.62162539766735 55.755972617558065,37.60574672029919 55.755972617558065,37.60574672029919 55.76360304012307)), ((37.65310224248083 55.76408915667978,37.69576009465368 55.76408915667978,37.69576009465368 55.74327126367862,37.65310224248083 55.74327126367862,37.65310224248083 55.76408915667978)))
```

This is what it looks like on a map.

[image]

These are the resulting hexagons.

```
MULTIPOLYGON(((37.616284080162494 55.75749587534617,37.61691435094995 55.75693498087154,37.618044116645436 55.757001523709455,37.61854364272989 55.75762896752626,37.6179133750184 55.75818987125727,37.61678357814598 55.758123321914994)),((37.61250216381124 55.76086109517582,37.6131325179221 55.76030024270741,37.61426233450115 55.760366834316756,37.6147618281481 55.76099428489984,37.614131477109275 55.76155514662441,37.613001629350855 55.76148854850967)),((37.614131477109275 55.76155514662441,37.6147618281481 55.76099428489984,37.61589168164416 55.761060865132876,37.61639121528237 55.76168831359522,37.61576086731764 55.76224918457605,37.61463098263997 55.762182597838155)),((37.61915060665912 55.762448886267414,37.619780929173686 55.76188799089943,37.62091086223679 55.76195453049221,37.62141050397119 55.76258197195621,37.62078018453669 55.763142876580865,37.619650220287156 55.763076330484765)),((37.61452402704689 55.75799019397347,37.6151543202009 55.75742931462781,37.616284080162494 55.75749587534617,37.61678357814598 55.758123321914994,37.61615328806596 55.758684210516904,37.61502349692789 55.75861764329365)),((37.609505733638024 55.75709636476695,37.61013605529576 55.756535519062474,37.6112657356971 55.75660212040765,37.61176512561169 55.75722957396369,37.61113480702192 55.757790428924004,37.610005095449026 55.75772382107239)),((37.6112657356971 55.75660212040765,37.611896034993045 55.7560412595741,37.61302572113419 55.756107843040716,37.61352513915084 55.75673529384669,37.61289484292486 55.7572961639362,37.61176512561169 55.75722957396369)),((37.61980413649265 55.7565071390634,37.62043436254456 55.75594621433197,37.621564139701 55.75601272140809,37.62206372198287 55.7566401597189,37.62143349901089 55.757201093707,37.62030369067654 55.757134580127534)),((37.60885076372684 55.76303779302333,37.60948118187133 55.76247697669237,37.61061101814752 55.76254361056972,37.611110467458744 55.76317106728433,37.61048005238236 55.76373189287117,37.60935018492607 55.76366525248742)),((37.60787673714715 55.756402287122526,37.60850706187088 55.75584145067377,37.60963670536077 55.7559080633903,37.61013605529576 55.756535519062474,37.609505733638024 55.75709636476695,37.60837605897875 55.75702974554347)),((37.6127639573017 55.75848447959124,37.613394272821466 55.75792361537491,37.61452402704689 55.75799019397347,37.61502349692789 55.75861764329365,37.61439318448013 55.75917851676611,37.61326339907877 55.759111931662176)),((37.610741976493436 55.761355323023274,37.611372352971664 55.760794485685565,37.61250216381124 55.76086109517582,37.613001629350855 55.76148854850967,37.61237125594268 55.762049395103396,37.611241413924255 55.76198277910719)),((37.61426233450115 55.760366834316756,37.614892666243854 55.75980596671802,37.61602248856005 55.759872540446125,37.61652201031282 55.760499988277836,37.61589168164416 55.761060865132876,37.6147618281481 55.76099428489984)),((37.617651869544275 55.76056655062884,37.618282175842005 55.76000565864372,37.619412040806516 55.76007220311244,37.61991163065526 55.76069964607004,37.619281327435566 55.76126054731169,37.6181514312885 55.76119399633914)),((37.618044116645436 55.757001523709455,37.61867436506552 55.756440614106246,37.61980413649265 55.7565071390634,37.62030369067654 55.757134580127534,37.61967344533443 55.757695498987296,37.61854364272989 55.75762896752626)),((37.6179133750184 55.75818987125727,37.61854364272989 55.75762896752626,37.61967344533443 55.757695498987296,37.620173011406074 55.75832294068309,37.61954274677258 55.758883853670625,37.618412912988916 55.75881731570574)),((37.61263306426401 55.75967279000478,37.61326339907877 55.759111931662176,37.61439318448013 55.75917851676611,37.614892666243854 55.75980596671802,37.61426233450115 55.760366834316756,37.6131325179221 55.76030024270741)),((37.61061101814752 55.76254361056972,37.611241413924255 55.76198277910719,37.61237125594268 55.762049395103396,37.61287073336441 55.762676849067915,37.61224034065779 55.763237689786436,37.611110467458744 55.76317106728433)),((37.61400061230388 55.76274345368803,37.61463098263997 55.762182597838155,37.61576086731764 55.76224918457605,37.61626041284185 55.76287663366857,37.61563004557982 55.76343749877469,37.61450012971891 55.76337090553198)),((37.61615328806596 55.758684210516904,37.61678357814598 55.758123321914994,37.6179133750184 55.75818987125727,37.618412912988916 55.75881731570574,37.61778262598488 55.759378213564084,37.616652797933824 55.75931165771744)),((37.61589168164416 55.761060865132876,37.61652201031282 55.760499988277836,37.617651869544275 55.76056655062884,37.6181514312885 55.76119399633914,37.61752110569587 55.761754882450575,37.61639121528237 55.76168831359522)),((37.606116752318414 55.756896477847995,37.606747099401126 55.75633565652849,37.60787673714715 55.756402287122526,37.60837605897875 55.75702974554347,37.607745714960025 55.75759057611853,37.606616046045104 55.757523939016984)),((37.61739033443911 55.762943209028265,37.61802067932779 55.76238232879101,37.61915060665912 55.762448886267414,37.619650220287156 55.763076330484765,37.619019878476536 55.76363721997857,37.61788991995925 55.76357065599836)),((37.60585459958918 55.75927302583512,37.60648498526554 55.75871221626454,37.607614685350995 55.758778859873566,37.60811403093181 55.7594063195605,37.6074836483195 55.759967138386635,37.60635391706175 55.75990048827018)),((37.61563004557982 55.76343749877469,37.61626041284185 55.76287663366857,37.61739033443911 55.762943209028265,37.61788991995925 55.76357065599836,37.61725955577332 55.76413153036091,37.616129602990576 55.76406494849687)),((37.60709049268375 55.76353194246413,37.60772093319518 55.7629711412651,37.60885076372684 55.76303779302333,37.60935018492607 55.76366525248742,37.60871974748072 55.764226062942164,37.60758988576947 55.76415940467702)),((37.6092437679349 55.759472951797925,37.60987412818384 55.75891211784134,37.61100387093002 55.75897873219941,37.611503284601625 55.75960618702042,37.610872927420715 55.760167030232836,37.609743153499586 55.76010040936834)),((37.6074836483195 55.759967138386635,37.60811403093181 55.7594063195605,37.6092437679349 55.759472951797925,37.609743153499586 55.76010040936834,37.60911277395331 55.76066123745019,37.60798300577573 55.76059459870584)),((37.607614685350995 55.758778859873566,37.60824504866594 55.75821803517271,37.60937475449627 55.75828466090315,37.60987412818384 55.75891211784134,37.6092437679349 55.759472951797925,37.60811403093181 55.7594063195605)),((37.607745714960025 55.75759057611853,37.60837605897875 55.75702974554347,37.609505733638024 55.75709636476695,37.610005095449026 55.75772382107239,37.60937475449627 55.75828466090315,37.60824504866594 55.75821803517271)),((37.61224034065779 55.763237689786436,37.61287073336441 55.762676849067915,37.61400061230388 55.76274345368803,37.61450012971891 55.76337090553198,37.61386974008436 55.76393175550664,37.612739829962116 55.763865144381136)),((37.619412040806516 55.76007220311244,37.62004232473254 55.759511295997555,37.62117219542784 55.75957782258372,37.6216718133796 55.76020526278796,37.62104153253363 55.76076617915949,37.61991163065526 55.76069964607004)),((37.61778262598488 55.759378213564084,37.618412912988916 55.75881731570574,37.61954274677258 55.758883853670625,37.62004232473254 55.759511295997555,37.619412040806516 55.76007220311244,37.618282175842005 55.76000565864372)),((37.61302572113419 55.756107843040716,37.613655998067536 55.75554696707846,37.61478568994617 55.75561353266617,37.61528513606343 55.756240980721465,37.61465486220202 55.75680186593983,37.61352513915084 55.75673529384669)),((37.6055924171585 55.761649552852475,37.60622284143312 55.76108875503284,37.60735260386488 55.76115541165676,37.60785197319708 55.76178287260769,37.607221551986505 55.76234367968293,37.60609175837908 55.76227701655155)),((37.60572351208684 55.76046129196552,37.60635391706175 55.75990048827018,37.6074836483195 55.759967138386635,37.60798300577573 55.76059459870584,37.60735260386488 55.76115541165676,37.60622284143312 55.76108875503284)),((37.616414864850285 55.75630753493492,37.61704511634632 55.755746634588114,37.61817485086661 55.75581317092161,37.61867436506552 55.756440614106246,37.618044116645436 55.757001523709455,37.61691435094995 55.75693498087154)),((37.60546131480352 55.76283780849497,37.60609175837908 55.76227701655155,37.607221551986505 55.76234367968293,37.60772093319518 55.7629711412651,37.60709049268375 55.76353194246413,37.60596066789893 55.763465272825286)),((37.61465486220202 55.75680186593983,37.61528513606343 55.756240980721465,37.616414864850285 55.75630753493492,37.61691435094995 55.75693498087154,37.616284080162494 55.75749587534617,37.6151543202009 55.75742931462781)),((37.61100387093002 55.75897873219941,37.61163420881477 55.75841788311279,37.6127639573017 55.75848447959124,37.61326339907877 55.759111931662176,37.61263306426401 55.75967279000478,37.611503284601625 55.75960618702042)),((37.60898177255083 55.76184951785901,37.60961217139562 55.76128869565234,37.610741976493436 55.761355323023274,37.611241413924255 55.76198277910719,37.61061101814752 55.76254361056972,37.60948118187133 55.76247697669237)),((37.61237125594268 55.762049395103396,37.613001629350855 55.76148854850967,37.614131477109275 55.76155514662441,37.61463098263997 55.762182597838155,37.61400061230388 55.76274345368803,37.61287073336441 55.762676849067915)),((37.607221551986505 55.76234367968293,37.60785197319708 55.76178287260769,37.60898177255083 55.76184951785901,37.60948118187133 55.76247697669237,37.60885076372684 55.76303779302333,37.60772093319518 55.7629711412651)),((37.61439318448013 55.75917851676611,37.61502349692789 55.75861764329365,37.61615328806596 55.758684210516904,37.616652797933824 55.75931165771744,37.61602248856005 55.759872540446125,37.614892666243854 55.75980596671802)),((37.61967344533443 55.757695498987296,37.62030369067654 55.757134580127534,37.62143349901089 55.757201093707,37.62193309318218 55.757828532649484,37.62130285092005 55.7583894607659,37.620173011406074 55.75832294068309)),((37.61113480702192 55.757790428924004,37.61176512561169 55.75722957396369,37.61289484292486 55.7572961639362,37.613394272821466 55.75792361537491,37.6127639573017 55.75848447959124,37.61163420881477 55.75841788311279)),((37.61576086731764 55.76224918457605,37.61639121528237 55.76168831359522,37.61752110569587 55.761754882450575,37.61802067932779 55.76238232879101,37.61739033443911 55.762943209028265,37.61626041284185 55.76287663366857)),((37.60735260386488 55.76115541165676,37.60798300577573 55.76059459870584,37.60911277395331 55.76066123745019,37.60961217139562 55.76128869565234,37.60898177255083 55.76184951785901,37.60785197319708 55.76178287260769)),((37.61752110569587 55.761754882450575,37.6181514312885 55.76119399633914,37.619281327435566 55.76126054731169,37.619780929173686 55.76188799089943,37.61915060665912 55.762448886267414,37.61802067932779 55.76238232879101)),((37.61602248856005 55.759872540446125,37.616652797933824 55.75931165771744,37.61778262598488 55.759378213564084,37.618282175842005 55.76000565864372,37.617651869544275 55.76056655062884,37.61652201031282 55.760499988277836)),((37.60911277395331 55.76066123745019,37.609743153499586 55.76010040936834,37.610872927420715 55.760167030232836,37.611372352971664 55.760794485685565,37.610741976493436 55.761355323023274,37.60961217139562 55.76128869565234)),((37.60937475449627 55.75828466090315,37.610005095449026 55.75772382107239,37.61113480702192 55.757790428924004,37.61163420881477 55.75841788311279,37.61100387093002 55.75897873219941,37.60987412818384 55.75891211784134)),((37.61289484292486 55.7572961639362,37.61352513915084 55.75673529384669,37.61465486220202 55.75680186593983,37.6151543202009 55.75742931462781,37.61452402704689 55.75799019397347,37.613394272821466 55.75792361537491)),((37.60963670536077 55.7559080633903,37.610267007724666 55.75534721181258,37.61139665695617 55.755413806651326,37.611896034993045 55.7560412595741,37.6112657356971 55.75660212040765,37.61013605529576 55.756535519062474)),((37.610872927420715 55.760167030232836,37.611503284601625 55.75960618702042,37.61263306426401 55.75967279000478,37.6131325179221 55.76030024270741,37.61250216381124 55.76086109517582,37.611372352971664 55.760794485685565)),((37.605985679666155 55.75808475446225,37.606616046045104 55.757523939016984,37.607745714960025 55.75759057611853,37.60824504866594 55.75821803517271,37.607614685350995 55.758778859873566,37.60648498526554 55.75871221626454)),((37.619281327435566 55.76126054731169,37.61991163065526 55.76069964607004,37.62104153253363 55.76076617915949,37.62154116237643 55.761393619993854,37.62091086223679 55.76195453049221,37.619780929173686 55.76188799089943)),((37.61954274677258 55.758883853670625,37.620173011406074 55.75832294068309,37.62130285092005 55.7583894607659,37.6218024569813 55.7590169003395,37.62117219542784 55.75957782258372,37.62004232473254 55.759511295997555)))
```

And what they look like on a map.

[image]

In the script itself `geometry.getNumGeometries` returns 2 which means it identified all polygons.

I thought it might be because of the `getGeometryN(0)` in the

```
points = List(
geometry
.getGeometryN(0)
.getCoordinates
.toList
.map(coord => new GeoCoord(coord.y, coord.x)): _*)
```

And tried to manualy concat getGeometryN(0) and getGeometryN(1) but got same hexagons

```
points = List(
  geometry
    .getGeometryN(0)
    .getCoordinates
    .toList
    .map(coord => new GeoCoord(coord.y, coord.x)): _*) ++
  List(
    geometry
      .getGeometryN(1)
      .getCoordinates
      .toList
      .map(coord => new GeoCoord(coord.y, coord.x)): _*)
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

If I replace point with this.

```
points = List(
  geometry
    .getGeometryN(0)
    .getCoordinates
    .toList
    .map(coord => new GeoCoord(coord.y, coord.x)): _*) ++
  List(
    geometry
      .getGeometryN(1)
      .getCoordinates
      .toList
      .map(coord => new GeoCoord(coord.y, coord.x)): _*)
```

And holes with

```
holes = (2 until numGeometries).toList.map(n => {
  List(
    geometry
      .getGeometryN(n)
      .getCoordinates
      .toList
      .map(coord => new GeoCoord(coord.y, coord.x)): _*).asJava
})
```

I get 2 sets of hexagons. But what If don't know what my multipolygon looks like? I can't manualy set every property.

Comment: I suspect that your problem is most likely in the in-compatibilty of your geometry list with the H3 part.

Comment: @sar Then I would be getting class cast exception, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from chat gpt and some time I managed to solve it)

Input wkt.

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((4.466801 50.432033, 4.497528 50.43247, 4.50079 50.419238, 4.476242 50.412784, 4.466801 50.432033), (4.472122 50.430174, 4.478645 50.430393, 4.478989 50.426948, 4.47298 50.426347, 4.472122 50.430174), (4.481392 50.425581, 4.482765 50.420441, 4.493065 50.421972, 4.489803 50.426019, 4.481392 50.425581)), ((4.514694 50.433017, 4.515381 50.415956, 4.543533 50.415409, 4.546795 50.431158, 4.514694 50.433017)), ((4.491348 50.407314, 4.491348 50.391557, 4.534607 50.390244, 4.491348 50.407314)))
```

Here is what it looks like.

[image]

And this is my script.

```
  def getHexagonsFromWKT(wkt: String, resolution: Int): Set[String] = {
    val geometry: Geometry = new WKTReader().read(wkt)
    var hexagons = List[String]()
    val numGeometries = geometry.getNumGeometries

    for (i <- 0 until numGeometries) {
      val points = List(geometry
        .getGeometryN(i)
        .getCoordinates
        .toList
        .map(coord => new GeoCoord(coord.y, coord.x)): _* )

      val numInteriorRings = geometry.getGeometryN(i).asInstanceOf[Polygon].getNumInteriorRing
      val holes = (0 until numInteriorRings).toList.map(n => {
        List(
          geometry
            .getGeometryN(i)
            .asInstanceOf[Polygon]
            .getInteriorRingN(n)
            .getCoordinates
            .toList
            .map(coord => new GeoCoord(coord.y, coord.x)): _*).asJava
      })
      hexagons :::= H3.instance.polyfillAddress(points, holes.asJava, resolution).toList
    }

    hexagons.toSet
  }
```

And the result after converting h3 address to polygins.

[image]

Also my dependencies. Just in case.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datasyslab</groupId>
    <artifactId>geospark</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datasyslab</groupId>
    <artifactId>geospark-sql_2.3</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.uber</groupId>
    <artifactId>h3</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```